# Why is my TERM not being captured

Tags: ruby, linux, unix

I have this sample code:

```
pid = Process.spawn("exec ruby -e \"trap('TERM'){ puts 'GOT TERM'; sleep 100; }; sleep 100\"")
Thread.new do
  Process.wait(pid)
end

p `ps aux | grep #{pid} | grep -v grep`

`kill -TERM #{pid}`
sleep 1

p `ps aux | grep #{pid} | grep -v grep`
```

It spawns a process that captures TERM and then sends a TERM to it.

Trouble is, TERM is not being captured here and process simply terminates.

```
ruby test.rb
"sam       8828  0.0  0.0  30576  5052 pts/9    Rl+  11:48   0:00 ruby -e trap('TERM'){ puts 'GOT TERM'; sleep 100; }; sleep 100\n"
""
```

**However** ... If I just sleep after the spawn and issue the kill from a different process the TERM is captured as expected.

```
pid = Process.spawn("exec ruby -e \"trap('TERM'){ puts 'GOT TERM'; sleep 100; }; sleep 100\"")
Thread.new do
  Process.wait(pid)
end
puts pid
sleep 100
```

Other shell

```
kill -TERM PID
```

Output

```
GOT TERM
```

Further more, if I try to then `kill` the process from the originating process after its trapped in the handler TERM will no longer kill it.

What is going on here, why is TERM not being delivered correctly to my child process from the parent?

Comment: interesting... what OS are you on? for me it works fine (MacOS):

`"<username>          71794   0.0  0.1  2443544   2932 s001  R+    9:22PM   0:00.01 ruby -e trap('TERM'){ puts 'GOT TERM'; sleep 100; }; sleep 100\n"

GOT TERM

"<username>          71794   0.6  0.2  2471356   8168 s001  S+    9:22PM   0:00.05 ruby -e trap('TERM'){ puts 'GOT TERM'; sleep 100; }; sleep 100\n"`

Comment: on linux ... I am actually suspecting this is linux specific and related to the way "exec" operates, a second pid is getting involved

Comment: It looks like there are many PIDs getting involved. I was investigating the behavior via strace, and found for one invocation of your script a total of 14(1) PID trace files were created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ahh, I get it,

TERM is being sent to the process too early, before the Ruby interpreter was able to establish the hook. So it terminates it.

a `sleep 1` before `kill -TERM #{pid}` sorts the issue out.

Comment: Trivial in the hindsight, indeed. :) `Thread.pass` may also work instead of `sleep`, but again it may be system-dependent.

Comment: what do you mean by "establish the hook"? if Process.spawn has returned with a pid, shouldn't the process be immediately receptive to signals?

Comment: ohhh the ruby interpreter invoked inside the Process hasn't spooled up yet… gotcha.